# Given L1 and L2 in NP, if L1 transforms L2 and L2 transforms HC then L1 NP complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, np-complete, np-hard, np

Why this Question is False ?

NP-complete problems are the hardest problems in NP.
if L is in NP-complete then [L must be in NP, all problems in NP can be transformed to L].

Does this mean that L2 is also NP-complete ? 
and if so does this also mean that L1 is NP-complete by transitivity ?
[image]

Comment: For showing in NP, you can show reduction from your problem to some problem in NP. And for proving a problem in NP is NP-complete, you can reduce any NP complete problem to your problem.

Comment: What is HC here?

Comment: hamiltonian circuit ( known to be NP-complete)